# Knockout select data-bind

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, knockout.js, bootstrap-4

I'm new to knockout, and got a question about using data-binds and the "option" binding. I want to have two drop downs, with data from my database. I can get the first one to work, but the second one does not appear even if I implement it in the same way. Only the first drop down will appear in the page, with all the correct data. But the second one that is supposed to appear with all the room names, does not appear. But when I remove the first one the second one works. I have obviously missed something here, what could it be?

This is my HTML-code:

```
<div align = "center">
    <select data-bind="options: employees, 
        optionsText: 'FullName', 
        value: Id, 
        optionsCaption: 'Select employee to login'"class = "container">
    </select>
</div>  

<div align = "center">
    <select data-bind="options: meetingRooms, 
        optionsText: 'Location', 
        value: Id, 
        optionsCaption: 'Choose room to book'" class = "container">
     </select>
</div>
```

And this is the java script code:

```
function BookingSystemViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.employees = ko.observableArray();
    self.meetingRooms = ko.observableArray();

    $.get( "/WebApi/API/Employees", function(data) {
        self.employees(data);
    });

     $.get( "/WebApi/API/MeetingRooms", function(data) {
        self.meetingRooms(data);
    });
```

Comment: can you get us a JSFiddle that replicates the issue because I don't see any code thats wrong

Comment: @LiefdeWen jsfiddle.net/j6dwt9vu/1 this is the code, but the data does not appear in the drop down as it is on my computer. The first drop down work as expected (i get all the data from my database), but the second one does not appear. But the second one works when I delete the first one, and I can see all that data also. But it is like something is blocked when having them both

Comment: here's a quick demo based on your code  http://plnkr.co/edit/VU17hMvaFKhLlMrA0EX8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div align = "center">
    <select data-bind="options: employees, 
        optionsText: 'FullName', 
        value: Id, 
        optionsCaption: 'Select employee to login'"class = "container">
    </select>
</div>  

<div align = "center">
    <select data-bind="options: meetingRooms, 
        optionsText: 'Location', 
        value: Id, 
        optionsCaption: 'Choose room to book'" class = "container">
     </select>
</div>
```

You are saying that `value` should be written to an observable named `Id` which you don't have in your view model. Maybe you're looking for `optionsValue` which is used to define what property you want to use as the value from the selected object.

Comment: @Chris If this worked, you should upvote to thank Joonas and mark his answer as accepted for future people who find the same problem as you